# exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to concat two string from a datatable and display it in a rich text box.

I get "exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" error when executing below code. Kindly help.

```
Rchtxt_Editor1.Document 
= ImportHtml(string.Concat("<P>string1</P>","<P>string2</P>"));


       public RadDocument ImportHtml(string content)
        {
 XamlFormatProvider provider = new XamlFormatProvider();
            return provider.Import(content);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the message of the error?

Comment: What is content ? any sample data you can provide ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: @ManuToMatic: the message is always the same: it's stated in the title and won't help solving the issue

Comment: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Comment: TargetInvocationExceptions usually have inner exceptions look at those

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned `TargetInvocationExceptions` usually have inner exceptions, use a try/catch block to see what is in the inner exception:

```
try
{
    Rchtxt_Editor1.Document = ImportHtml(string.Concat("<P>string1</P>", "<P>string2</P>"));
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}

public RadDocument ImportHtml(string content)
{
    try
    {
        XamlFormatProvider provider = new XamlFormatProvider();
        return provider.Import(content);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

After this place a watch on `ex` variable and see what the inner exception is, then you will know what the actual issue is:

[image]